# Optimizing ingestion queries in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to ingested a graph that contains ~ 100 nodes, but ~ 10K relationships that are timestamped.

After some research, I have used batch transactions & was able to bring down the ingestion time from 6min to ~ 40s using UNWIND on my local machine (localhost)

However, when I send the same batch transactions of 10K relationships to a different server, it is taking more than 3min.

What strategies can I use to reduce ingestion time to neo4j on a remote server? (My reason why I have hosted remote server was to separate neo4j execution cycles from my pc which has to do a lot of nlp tasks needed for my application, server is on my lan & I am the only user connected to it using ip-address).

My ingestion query is here:

```
  result = cypher.query("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:USPolitics) ASSERT n.id IS UNIQUE",map());

  parameters = createrelations();
  result = cypher.query(
          "UNWIND {batches} as batch " +
                  "MATCH (nodeA {id: batch.nodeA})"+
                  "MATCH (nodeB {id: batch.nodeB})"+
                  "MERGE (nodeA)-[rel:KNOWS]->(nodeB)" +
                  "ON CREATE SET rel+=batch.properties " +
                  "RETURN 1", parameters);
```

Comment: You forgot the label on the nodes for `MATCH` see Dave's answer.

Comment: You don't have to return anything, or can just `return count(*)`

Answer (score 2):

You will want to add the label `USPolitics` to your query to ensure the index from the constraint you created is being used. Presuming of course that `nodeA` and `nodeB` are in fact `USPolitics` nodes.

```
result = cypher.query("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:USPolitics) ASSERT n.id IS UNIQUE",map());

parameters = createrelations();
result = cypher.query(
      "UNWIND {batches} as batch " +
              "MATCH (nodeA:USPolitics {id: batch.nodeA})"+
              "MATCH (nodeB:USPolitics {id: batch.nodeB})"+
              "MERGE (nodeA)-[rel:KNOWS]->(nodeB)" +
              "ON CREATE SET rel+=batch.properties " +
              "RETURN 1", parameters);
```